# Declare a TypeScript enum in JSDoc

Tags: typescript, jsdoc, tsc

How does one use JSDoc `@typedef`s to declare a TypeScript `enum` in a .js file? (This is for a piece of legacy code that cannot yet be migrated to TypeScript, but needs to be imported into a TypeScript module.)

Note that JSDoc's `@enum` is [*not* compatible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#enum) with TypeScript's `enum`.

The goal is for `tsc` to emit the following `.d.ts` contents:

```
declare const enum MyEnum {
  Apple = "apple",
  Banana = "banana",
  Carrot = "carrot",
}
```

#### Failed attempts

The following do *not* work:

```
const MyEnum = /** @type {const} */ {
  Apple: "apple",
  Banana: "banana",
  Carrot: "carrot",
};

//  TypeScript generates the following `.d.ts`:

declare const MyEnum: {
  Apple: "apple";
  Banana: "banana";
  Carrot: "carrot";
};
```

```
/**
 * @typedef {enum { Apple = 'apple', Banana = 'banana', Carrot = 'carrot' }} MyEnum // ❌ invalid syntax
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `typeof e[keyof typeof e]` to get the values of type

```
const MyEnum = /** @type {const} */ ({
    kApple: "apple",
    kBanana: "banana",
    kCarrot: "carrot",
});
// const MyEnum: {
//     readonly kApple: "apple";
//     readonly kBanana: "banana";
//     readonly kCarrot: "carrot";
// }

/**
 * @typedef {typeof MyEnum[keyof typeof MyEnum]} MyEnum 
 */
// type MyEnum = "apple" | "banana" | "carrot"

/** @type {MyEnum} */
let v = 'apple'
// let v: MyEnum
```